# Set empty values in geom_tile to be 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
structure(list(pred = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("eGFP", "EV.BC9", "P53.BC1", 
"P53.BC2", "P53.BC3", "P53.BC4", "R175H.P53.BC5", "R175H.P53.BC6", 
"R175H.P53.BC7", "R175H.P53.BC8"), class = "factor"), ref = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("R175H.P53.BC8", 
"R175H.P53.BC7", "R175H.P53.BC6", "R175H.P53.BC5", "P53.BC4", 
"P53.BC3", "P53.BC2", "P53.BC1", "EV.BC9", "eGFP"), class = "factor"), 
    count = c(6L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 12L, 148L, 1L, 
    1L, 83L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 78L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    4L, 121L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 39L, 1L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 
    3L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 52L, 2L, 
    2L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), groups = structure(list(
    pred = structure(1:10, .Label = c("eGFP", "EV.BC9", "P53.BC1", 
    "P53.BC2", "P53.BC3", "P53.BC4", "R175H.P53.BC5", "R175H.P53.BC6", 
    "R175H.P53.BC7", "R175H.P53.BC8"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:10, 11:14, 15:21, 22:30, 31:32, 33:37, 38:45, 46:51, 
        52:54, 55:60), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I then make this plot:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = pred,
      y = ref,
      fill = count
    )
  ) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(trans = "log10") + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```

[image: example]

This plot needs a bit of work but illustrates my point, it is trying to visually represent a confusion matrix.

However, there are combinations of classes in my data that are missing. Is there a way for me to add to my data the rest of the combinations I am missing with a count of 0? Or just to have all the missing tiles put in and have them coloured like they had a count of 0?

Many thanks

Comment: @-notify me if you don't think the duplicate is right.

Comment: P.S. The dark purple color at the bottom of the scale should be `"#440154FF"`.

Comment: I saw it before I asked my question and didn't think it did. But after some perseverence I fixed the error and managed to expand my tibble and impute 0's into my counts column. Then just had to adjust my colour scale to "log1p". Thanks very much and sorry for the duplicate!